# Compare selected radio button to field in table

Tags: php, mysql

How do I check the selected radio button value with the value stored in a database field? Code is below:

index.php:

```
    dfdfdffdfdfdfdf
```

question.php

```
$_POST['answer'];
$totalCorrect = 0;

if ($_POST == 'CorrectAnswer') { $totalCorrect++;}

echo "$totalCorrect questions correct";
```

I want to pass the answer chosen to check it with the database to see if it matches the value of `CorrectAnswer` and edit the score accordingly.

Comment: $_POST is an array, you can't compare it to a string. Check your if-statement.

Comment: And by the way, you generate invalid HTML. HTML-attributes must be enclosed in double-quotes (`"`). Simply exchange `"` to `'` and vice versa.`echo '<input type="radio" name="answer" value="'.$key.'">".$value;`

Comment: D'oh, silly me! I'm only just starting to dabble in PHP, guess I have a lot to learn. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

You missed to access the 'answer' index when accessing `$_POST`. Use:

```
if ($_POST['answer'] == 'CorrectAnswer') { $totalCorrect++;}
```

instead.

Comment: Well this doesn't throw up errors but even if I am clicking the right answer and hitting 'Submit' it's just saying `0 questions correct`. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: It's a perfect bad design - and will never work. I don't know where I should start to explain without giving you the full solution. :|

Comment: Oh, okay. The basic idea is a PHP Facebook quiz game that pulls questions and answers from a database table to populate the quiz so to speak and checks the selected answer with the correct one stored in a field in the table. Is there any way I can email you / discuss further?

Comment: Sorry, you cannot expect to get a full working application on SO. You will find a ton of tutorials on google. I would suggest that you start with a simple quiz and later if it is working than add the facebook functionality

Comment: Part of the requirements is that it has to be a Facebook app and have certain levels of interactivity. I'm not expecting a full working app, but how am I supposed to know how to improve if I just get told it's bad and will never work with no explanation as to why?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
if ($_POST['answer'] == 'CorrectAnswer') { $totalCorrect++;}
```

N.B. you don't need the `method` attribute on your submit button as this is already declared in the `<form>` tag.